# Doxygen: How to create new special command?

Tags: doxygen

I would like to create a new special command in doxygen to document, e.g., the algorithmic complexity or the space complexity of a function, and have it emit a special paragraph in the documentation like the commands `\pre`, `\warning`,... (in particular I like the color bar next to the paragraphs using these commands).

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Did you have a look at the ALIAS possibility in the Doxyfile. Regarding the colored line, possibly you cn find a solution in specifying an own css files / do some postprocessing on the result.

Comment: yes, but in particular the colored line can't be easily achieved with ALIAS, im using the convention of writing \par Name and then the property stuff in a new line, without colored line. But it is far from an ideal solution.